# Behance API Ajax load content

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, api

I am trying to get the following code to work in order to load the project content into the page on selection of an image. I have the images loading from the behance api, but I am struggling with the second bit when the a is selected it should take the url from the page and add it to the JSON to load each project content into the page. Can anyone see where I am ogin

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
var jqxhr;
jqxhr = $.getJSON("http://www.behance.net/v2/users/USER/projects?api_key=KEY&callback=?", function(data) {
    var project_str = "";
    for(var i=0; i<  data.projects.length; i++){
        obj = {};
          obj = data.projects[i];
project_str += '<a class="link" href="#' + obj.id  + '"><img src="' + obj.covers['404'] + '" /></a>';       }
    $('#behance_container div').append(project_str);
});
          });

$('a.link').click(function(){
var hash = location.hash.replace("#","");
var jqxhri;
jqxhri = $.getJSON("http://www.behance.net/v2/projects/' + hash + '?api_key=KEY&callback=?", function(data) {
    $('#behance_header h3').html(data.project.name);
    var project_data = '<p>' + data.project.description + '</p>';       
    $('#behance_project').html(project_data);   });
        });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='behance_container'>
    <div></div>  
    </div>
    <div id='behance_header'><h3></h3><p></p></div> <div id='behance_project'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can anyone see what I am doing wrong, as to why it isnt loading the content on selection, I could really do with some help

Comment: It's impossible to help without knowing what you're *trying to do*.  You've posted a big glob of code.  What's the intent?  What's not working, exactly?

Comment: It is impossible to read your code with messed up indentation.  Please format your code properly.

Comment: I have updated the code to show that I am trying to show that the first part loads the image wrapped in a URL, and the second part on click I want to take that URL and insert it into the JSON. Can anyone help with inserting the selected page URL after the hash?

Answer (score 0):

You are defining `getBehanceProject(id)` to take an `id` argument and you are using that argument in the function, but when you call the function, you do not pass an `id` argument.

Further, in `getBehanceProject(id)`, you are then defining a local variable called `id` too which should not be.

The first thing you should fix is to pass the desired id to `getBenhanceProject()` when you call it.

---

Secondly, you need to realize that `addBehance()` is asynchronous.  It will finish some time AFTER you call it.  So, in your current code, you will be calling `getBehanceProject()` BEFORE the AJAX call in `addBehance()` has completed which will probably cause a problem for your code.